# Como colocar aspas numa mensagem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoa.Nome))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Nome", "O campo nome é obrigatório");
}
```

Como faço para colocar aspas dentro da mensagem?

Ex.: O campo “nome” é obrigatório.

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError("Nome", "O campo \"nome\" é obrigatório");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras:

Usando barra invertida ():

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoa.Nome))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Nome", "O campo \"nome\" é obrigatório");
}
```

Ou usando o arroba (@) com aspas duplas duplicadas:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoa.Nome))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Nome", @"O campo ""nome"" é obrigatório");
}
```

Comment: A barra me parece ter mais lógica, indicando que aquele caractere faz parte do texto. Como funciona com o @? Ao invés de usar a barra eu uso aspas para indicar que é um texto?

Comment: Ao invés de usar a barra para escape, você utiliza as aspas duplas duplicadas. O segundo tem algumas aplicações interessantes, se você quiser usar barra-invertida, ao invés de colocar duas barras para escape, pode apenas inserir um @ na frente, conforme o segundo exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim